# Declaring a boolean : Default value

Tags: ios, objective-c, boolean

```
BOOL isChecked;
```

I declared the boolean like this.

Will it have the default value as **NO**? or What is its default value? [Did it have one?]

Should I always set the value to YES or NO myself in code?

Comment: oops sry tht was a typo *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BOOL isn't an object, so your sample code is declaring a pointer which isn't pointing anywhere. I think you mean:
`BOOL isChecked;`

Yes, you should initialize it yourself. In certain cases (globals, instance variables) the default initial value will be NO (0), but in others (locals) it will be undefined.

Comment: There are other scopes other than "globals" and "locals", for example when the variable is an instance variable, where it will also be intialized to `0` (`NO`).

Answer (score 1):

Generally you wouldn't create a pointer to a BOOL. Because it's a pointer it will have a default value of `nil`. It doesn't actually point to a BOOL until you assign it so there is no default for that.

Do you actually want `BOOL isChecked;`, which will have a default value of `NO`?

Comment: the doubt is that if I decare so what will be the value for `ischecked`?

Comment: If it's an instance variable you're fine, if it's local you can (and should) declare a default.

Answer (score 0):

If you are declaring a property, then it will have a default value of NO. Otherwise if it is a local instance variable, then you can't speculate it's value. :)

Answer (score 0):

If BOOL isChecked is a property or iVar then default value would be NO. But if it is a local variable then the value would some garbage.